# Repartitioning already mounted logical volumes

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

This is my current disk state on a physical CentOS machine:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_root
                       50G   47G  267M 100% /
tmpfs                 5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   63M  397M  14% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_home
                      406G  158G  227G  41% /home
```

As you can see my root partition is almost full and I need more space because additional log files cannot be written in the /var directory. This problem grew up after importing a huge database in /var/lib/mysql directory.

I have enough space on my logical volume lv_home but I don't know how can I get piece from lv_home without formatting and losing data from any of the partitions. Is it possible or I need to find another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, look at the man pages if you want more details on the specific commands;

```
umount /home
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_home {the size you want}
lvreduce -L-{the size you want} /dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_home
mount /home

lvextend -L +{the size you want} /dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_root
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_root {the size you want}
```

Comment: The following error is thrown when I am trying to mount the resized logical volume:


mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg_home-lv_home,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do, using a combination of `rezise2fs`, `lvreduce` and `lvextend`. It's quite dangerous, and I would not recommend doing this on a system with any data you care about. But if you want to try the procedure looks something like this:

```
#Shrink the filesystem to 200G
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_home 200G 
#Use a bit larger to avoid fatal off-by-something errors
lvreduce -L 210G /dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_home
#Regrow the filesystem to fill the partition
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_home 
#Extend the volume by 50G
lvextend -L+50G /dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_root 
#Grow the filesystem
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_ecomwise-lv_root
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to risk losing data due the partition/file system resizing, why not to stop MySQL, modify the home directory in `my.cnf`, move the database to `/home/mysql/db` or so and let MySQL store its data under /home?